# Can't find the right XPATH for python locator

Tags: python, html, xpath

I write locators, need to find the checkbox by the text of the span element. Tried this one but didn't work
`//span[text()='#1599064']/ancestor::div[@data-class-name='SourceView']/div/input`

Please help
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hljbi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only this information is difficult, but if the text is static you can try to locate that one using the developer console. If you're on Chrome/Firefox press F12, then under the Elements tab (on chrome) click the exact element you would like to extract the XPATH selector, then right click and Copy > Copy Xpath.

I hope this can help you .

Comment: there are several checkboxes on the page, and the text is a unique id. I need to select checkbox element with exactly this text-id using XPATH

Comment: if the text is static it's really easy with this method.

Comment: copy full XPATH considered wrong by my teacher

Comment: oh okay you didn't write it's for a homework... well, you can use this method to see which one is the correct. then you can extract elements with python.